# Assigning Tasks to Related User

Tags: workflow, tasks

We have been trying to assign a task to our Sales Engineers (Lookup Field on opp), they are not the Opp owner. The Sales Engineers are assigned to Opps in their own field once it reaches a specific point in the deal. The S.E.'s would like to have a task sent to them each time they have been assigned a Opp. I already have email notifications going out to them and daily reports, but they want a task in addition.

I know tasks cannot be assigned if its not the User, Role, Owner, or Creator. I tried to use Process Builder to work around it but failed. I thought of also creating multiple WF rules for each Engineer to receive a task if it meets a specific criteria of their name to that field, but this would just be a band-aid fix.

Comment: Are you using opportunity teams?

Comment: No we are not using Opp teams

Comment: That might be the solution to your problem. Use Opp Teams and add your Sales Engineers to the team. You shouldn't have any difficulties assigning them tasks once you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely be able to do this with process builder, I just tossed together a quick POC in my Dev org:

[image: Process]
[image: Criteria]
[image: Create Record]
[image: Test Result]

Comment: The SE isn't what changed. He's saying he doesn't have opp teams enabled and can't assign Tasks to SE's (as the owner of the Task) with a WhatID of OpportunityID. At least that's how I understand his question.

Comment: @crmprogdev I read it as he is using a lookup field instead of Opp Team and wants to generate a task when the SE is assigned to an Opp using that lookup field. I didn't add the related to id field in my test but you can assign that using reference to the Opp Id as well.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting/sending the email notification that is sent to the end user?

There's a very simple solution to this depending on the method used for sending the email - Let me know and I'll post the details.

Kev